# Bootstrap not being responsive under domain iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, dns

I've been developing a web using Bootstrap checking it working with the long url my hosting is providing me.

Recently I paid a domain name to cover that long url, and chose the redirect type to 'iframe'. The problem comes when I want to enter via smartphone. If I enter with the 'long url' everything gets the 'responsivity' is meant to show. However, if I enter with the 'paid url' everything gets shaped as if it's being used via computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Not the answer you were asking for, but why you not point the Domain name to your site directly? Since you added the `dns` flag, isn't that a solution? It definitely would be the best. iframes have several problems like  the user can not deep-link to a specific site, Search engines will link to the "long domain" directly, not the "paid domain". Some users (such as me) even have iframes disabled in their browsers.

Comment: Hi @DanielSchroeder, if I just redirect, then the 'long url' is being shown from the first time. Thank you for answering but I was looking for a code solution as I've already been changing options in my dns provider panel control and nothing better happened.

Comment: If you set up the DNS correctly, the domain name is not redirecting but pointing to the IP of your host. Then the ugly domain name is not involved at all and the user accesses the website through the nice domain name. For that you need to define either an  `A` or a `CNAME` record. See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) for a description of these. How this is exactly done in the interface of your provider you need to look up in their FAQ or contact the support if it is not obvious from the interface.

Comment: So @DanielSchroeder, as you say I should be able to set a CNAME to whatever url I'd like. But it says its not a valid url. If I try to set a CNAME to google.com it works, but if I try my real 'long url' it says it's wrong.
LONG URL: http://79.170.40.49/upvtests.es

Comment: DNS entries work per domain (Domain Name Service). That means you can not point to a specific "file". You can create a record pointing to `79.170.40.49`, but this would rather be an `A` record, not a `CNAME` (I believe). Accessing a specific "file" you need to handle on your host then. By default files like `index.html` etc. are accessed by default. You could rename your file to match that.

Comment: Though if your content is not available on the root `/` because the provider does not allow it (e.g. some free hosting) then the DNS solution indeed would not work. Your content needs to be accessible directly on the root for this to work.

Comment: I believe the problem (and solution) is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083391/godaddy-dns-forward-to-ip-adds-frames-to-html